# Using a custom font in project without htaccess / iis results in "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: css, fonts

I am creating a small project, where I intend to use a custom font.

Right now I am just running it locally on my Windows 8 machine, without any IIS / apache server.

I then get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

How to solve it? The other answers I could find on StackOverflow assumes the use of a server like apache (.htaccess) or a web.config on an IIS.

My code is as follows:

**Css**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_7_0.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_7_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_7_0.otf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_7_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_7_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_6_0.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_6_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_6_0.otf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_6_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_6_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_8_0.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_8_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_8_0.otf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_8_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova/2B61CF_8_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova';
}
```

**Html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like any other server, you will have to add the mimetype to your configuration file and restart the server. I have a background in nginx, but i found this page for IIS which should help you fix the problem.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Edit: according to this page, in IIS 7 you can add it on the command line like so:

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension=' eot ',mimeType=' font/eot ']"
```

basically you need to find the mime type list and add in your font

here's an example of font mime types and their extensions

```
        font/ttf ttf;
        font/otf otf;
        font/woff woff;
```